# Which data is globally shared data in HANA shared directory

Tags: hana

What is "globally shared data" in HANA shared directory? Is it the shared customer data or the shared administrative data?

Note from [SAP documentation - Recommended File System Layout](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/2c1988d620e04368aa4103bf26f17727/4c24d332a37b4a3caad3e634f9900a45.html):

> */hana/shared/ - Contains executable programs (exe), globally shared data (global), instance profiles (profile), and SAP HANA configuration files.*

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what is unclear with the official description. This OS level folder does not contain the database contents but the software components that are required to access the database (e.g. binaries for the server processes).